# Put DOM Element next to other element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using `stats.js` and I want to place its `stats.domElement` right next to the top right corner of a `canvas` I have on a page.

```
stats.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
stats.domElement.style.left = "20px";
stats.domElement.style.top = "20px";
```

Right now, that's my code, but I think it has to be "relative". I checked MDN Documentation in search for more information about domElement's relative positioning, but I couldn't find much.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
stats.domElement.style.right = "20px";
```

Comment: That puts the monitor a bit outside the page on the left bottom corner. I need to associate somehow with the element with `id="canvas"`, but I can't find any information on how to do that.

Comment: Perhaps creating a jsfiddle with your HTML and code will help.